# What is the error rate in compressed sensing?

Tags: discrete-signals, dsp-core, statistics, compressive-sensing

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a $k$-sparse vector. Given $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, we have a measurement vector $y$ given by

$$y=Ax$$

Let $\hat{x}$ be defined as follows

$$\hat{x}:=\arg\min_{z\in\mathbb{R}^n}\|z\|_1,\ \mbox{s.t}\ Az=y$$

Then, which of these two would be called *error rate*?

1. $\|\hat{x}-x\|_1$, or,
2. $\dfrac{\|\hat{x}-x\|_1}{\|x\|_1}$.

Comment: Do you know what $\|\mathbf{x}\|_1$ means?

Comment: Your $ \hat{x} $ isn't well defined. Are we looking for argument of which function?

Comment: $\|x\|_1$ is the $\ell_1$ norm.

Comment: What is $l_1$ norm?

Comment: argument of the function $\hat{x}$, which is called the basis pursuit.

Comment: @BlackMath; it is the some of the absolute values of  the element of $x$.

Comment: $x$ and $\hat{x}$ are drawn from a finite set of symbols, like $\{0,\,1\}$?

Comment: No, the $x,\ \hat{x}$ are any general vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Define $k$-sparse.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo a $k$-sparse vector is a vector in which at most $k$ entries are non-zero.